# Isn't this wikipedia equation of navier-stokes actually wrong?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

There is a wikipedia page about [NS Existance and Smoothness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_existence_and_smoothness)

It seems to me that the Navier Stokes equations is wrong?
(because in one side of equal sign unit is $\frac {m}{s^2}$ but in other side it is $\frac {kg.m}{s^2}$)
Navier Stokes Equation:

[image]

Comment: Your second link doesn't work. What do you think is wrong with the NS equation on Wikipedia?

Comment: I think this is off-topic, unless you can turn it into a much more specific question about the physical concepts involved. A better place to discuss it would be the [talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ehm, what do you think is wrong? You should be specific.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, as @Nathaniel said, the question belongs on the corresponding talk page of that Wikipedia entry. It is not the purpose of Phys.SE to correct all the typos of the Internet.

Comment: @Qmechanic how does Community edit posts? I always assumed it was just a robo-user that only bumped posts, but it appears to be controlled by somebody.

Comment: @tpg2114: It was a suggested edit from an anonymous unregistered user.

Comment: @Qmechanic A few months ago I stumbled upon that same Wikipedia page and had the exact same concern as the OP. It turns out the they are assuming the density term is absorbed into the pressure term. I didn't realize this for a few days even though there is a note about it in the Wikipedia page's text. I think this question is very much on topic provided the question is presented in the form of Revision 5 by Nathaniel so that it is a physics question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is incorrect. There should be a $\frac{1}{\rho}$ multiplying the $\nabla p$ term.

This form is the incompressible form where it is assumed $\rho$ is a constant. This allows it to be factored out of the derivatives on the left hand side, then both sides are divided by $\rho$. This is why there is kinematic viscosity, $\nu$ on the right and not molecular viscosity, $\mu$.

You must also define the force to be the body force (force*volume/mass), not the total force, otherwise there should be a $\frac{1}{\rho}$ factor there too.

Comment: This is because the equations have been nondimensionalised, i.e. the density has been eliminated by scaling all the other units so that $\rho=1$. This is fairly common practice in fluid mechanics, particularly among mathematicians, who don't really care about the physical interpretation.

Comment: @Nathaniel I disagree, $\nu$ is defined on the linked page as the kinematic viscosity and nowhere does it say things were non-dimensionalized. I concede it is the non-conservative form which is why $\rho$ could be pulled out of the derivatives on the LHS, but there is nothing to indicate that it was non-dimensionalized.

Comment: Oh, ok. I did jump to that conclusion without really reading the page.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page for the [Navier–Stokes existence and smoothness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_existence_and_smoothness) there is a [note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_existence_and_smoothness#cite_note-2) that addresses this discrepancy: "More precisely, p(x,t) is the pressure divided by the fluid density, and the density is constant for this incompressible and homogeneous fluid."

Comment: Given the note, it is "correct" as written; however, I wouldn't present it that way as clearly it is confusing. But that's up to wikipedia to settle and outside of the scope we have here.